# Not able to see container logs on docker host when I use awslogs driver

Tags: logging, docker-compose, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I set "stdout" in docker file to send application logs to docker host.
My requirement is to send containers logs to cloudwatch and docker host both.
For cloudwatch, I used awslogs driver in docker-compose but now logs are not showing in docker host[docker logs container].
I am using EC2 instance.

Error:

```
"logs" command is supported only for "json-file" and "journald" logging drivers (got: awslogs)
```

Please suggest how to implement both.

Answer (score 0):

At this time only enterprise edition 18.03.1-ee-1 version supports multiple log drivers

https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#older-docker-engine-ee-release-notes